# Do all games in the Trackmania series provide a track editor?

Tags: trackmania-series

There are quite a few games in the [Trackmania series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrackMania): do they all come with a track editor?

I am asking for the games of the Trackmania series that have been published so far (see list below):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I could find on Internet, all games in the Trackmania series provide a track editor:

[image]